# How can I muffle a speaker on a small TV?

Tags: speakers, sounds, electronics

I need background noise when I work and I often use a small TV in my study, either playing DVDs of old TV shows or tuned to a nostalgia channel.  I don't want sound to be too loud, though.

I recently bought a 7" TV that I can easily tuck out of the way, so I can still see the images once in a while, like I prefer, but it doesn't take up much space anywhere.  The only problem is that, for some videos and some channels, the minimum volume is still rather loud.  There's one channel I can have on that, with the volume set to 1, I can hear in surrounding rooms with the doors closed.

The speaker is on the back of the TV and is about 2" tall by 1" to 1.5" wide.  I used duct tape to tape some heavy cardboard over the speaker.  That helped, but not by much.  I can touch a spot, over the speaker, where I can press on the duct tape and cardboard just a little and it significantly muffles the sound.  I broke off about 2" off the end of two pencils and taped them down over the duct tape and cardboard covering, in hopes the stiffer pencils might hold down vibration, but it doesn't help much.

I've thought of trying to tape over something padded or a quilted fabric, but I don't have anything I can cut up.

What could I easily put together or use to tape over the speaker grill on the back of this small TV that would do a good job of muffling the speaker sound without fuzzing or distorting the sound?

Comment: Does the tv have an audio out port ? You could mute the tv speaker in the settings menu and send the audio to the audio out port and  to a stereo unit that has a more controllable volume.

Comment: Good thought - no audio output.  I think this is designed to use with things like Arduino or Raspberry Pi devices.  It has a jack and adapter for RCA audio (left & right) and video in, plus HDMI and DB15 in, but no output jacks - and no tuner, so, without input it's useless.

Comment: If it does not have a tuner then what about audio out on what ever device you are using to send content to the monitor ? Send video to the monitor and audio to a stereo.

Comment: Are you willing to hack the electronics?
You could disconnect one of the leads to the speaker internally, and maybe bring it out to a switch (to turn on/off), or add a jack that disconnects when plugged in, or adds a resistor inline.

Comment: @AlaskaMan: Good thought, but I have an HDMI switch and switch between the BD player and Apple TV and neither has an internal volume control.

Comment: @DaveM: On/Off isn't the issue.  I need to turn the sound down, which would require a pot.  Honestly, at one time, I could have worked it out, but it's been so long since I've done serious electronics, I can't remember what I need to do to make sure I get the resistance and/or impedance matched properly - plus I'd have a pot dangling off the TV.  (Although I might make it work with a jack, where I can plug and unplug the extra volume control - but I still need help working out what pot to use to match what I need to.)

Comment: Internal volume control is not the issue. Audio out ports are what you want, send the audio to a devise that has a volume control.

Comment: depending on the audio enclosure design, if it's otherwise well-sealed, your best bet could be to completely duct tape over the opening. You want to seal the air inside. That will have the effect of dramatically lowering the efficiency of the speaker, especially at bass, which is the hardest to attenuate without also killing off the needed treble

Comment: @dandavis: Duct tape, duct tape with cardboad - it muffles some, but not much.

Comment: yeah, i'm saying try it with no cardboard, just tape. you want each little hole on the grille plugged. as-is, your cardboard is acting like it's own speaker cone, which is why your finger muffles it.

Comment: For those watching this, I haven't skipped out without picking an answer.  I've had so much come up I haven't had time to try the second answer, by @AlaskaMan.  I know I have an HDMI breakout box I could use to feed the audio into my Sonos amp or into the speakers for my Yamaha keyboard.  It'll take time before I can find that breakout box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to duct taping a towel over your monitor speaker would be to:

Get a used [A/V receiver](https://www.dummies.com/consumer-electronics/home-theater/what-does-an-av-receiver-do/) at a thrift shop that has HDMI in/out.

Go >HDMI from Apple TV and Blue Ray >into the A/V unit and HDMI> out to the monitor.

A set of speakers connected to the A/V unit will handle the sound.

Volume control on the A/V unit will adjust the sound to the speakers.

Easypeasy macandcheesy. OR, Bobs your uncle. Depending on what side of the pond you are on.

Comment: That brings up something I had not thought about.  I have a Sonos speaker in my that has an input.  I can split the HDMI and take the audio out and pipe it into Sonos.  Or I think I can.  I'll have to look into that.

Comment: Just a note I tried other ways, with taping stuff over the speaker.  None worked reliably - either it didn't mute it enough, or it muffled it so it sounded different, or I got vibration sounds.  I finally had to dig for an HDMI/Audio splitter I knew I had around here and split it so I could play audio through my Sonos Line In connection.

Answer (score 2):

Get a small piece of foam padding (the stuff they use for chair cushions would work great) and tape that over the speaker.

You'll probably have to turn the volume up some.

Comment: What?  I just taped a big seat cushion over my monitor and i am not sure what you said. ;) Has anybody seen my mouse pointer so i can hit the back button ?

Comment: I have no problem with turning the volume up.  Even on softer volume videos and channels, I'm hardly ever going above 4 as it is.